# Why a WPF Style is applied to a parent control?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml

I defined a custom WPF Style. I want any button in the Grid is Red. But if I define this style, the **whole grid is red**!! Why? I explicitly defined Button.Background.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="MyStyle">
            <Setter Property="Button.Background" Value="Red" /> <!-- Only inner buttons -->
        </Style>            
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid Style="{StaticResource MyStyle}">
        <Button Content="Go" Margin="29,36,385,239" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you're after I think you're gonna have to define the inner `Style`s within `Style.Resources`. This will make all the `Button`s in the `Grid` pick up the "inner" `Style` unless they explictly use another `Style`

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MyStyle">
        <Style.Resources>
            <!-- Only inner buttons -->
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid Style="{StaticResource MyStyle}">
    <Button Content="Go" Margin="29,36,385,239" />
</Grid>
```

---

Since `Button.Background` isn't an attached property (unlike e.g. `TextBlock.Foreground`), the `Background` won't be applied to the `Button`s in the `Grid`.

But as for the "Why does the `Grid` pick up the `Background`" I couldn't tell you. It seems like a bug to me. **Background** for a `Button` is inherited from `Control` and **Background** for a `Grid` is inherited from `Panel` so as far as I can see, that value shouldn't be used by the `Grid` but I might be missing something

Also, you'll get the following error if you try to set `Button.Background` directly on a `Grid`

> error MC3015: The attached property
>   'Button.Background' is not defined on
>   'Grid' or one of its base classes.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you set the TargetType to button so that this style is only applied to a Button?

```
<Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="Button">
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
</Style>
```

Comment: No, because the style MUST be applied to the Grid. And should contains  all the different styles for the different inner controls

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, styles don't work like that.  If you have a known child collection, you can cheat with something like (ugly):

```
<Setter Property="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self} Path=Children[0].Background}" Value="Red" />
```

Of course, this only works if you know the children indices, and it's pretty fragile.  I'm not sure that it'll work for your case b/c you said that you *must* apply the style to the grid, so I'm guessing the grid contents are getting dynamically generated.